# Can someone figure out why the following function always returns false?

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop, boolean

```
bool ordered(int args, double num, ...)
{
    bool order = true;
    double holder1, holder2;
    va_list arguments;
    va_start(arguments, num);
    holder1 = va_arg(arguments, double);
    for(int x = 2; x < args + 1; x++)
    {
        if(x % 2 == 0)
        {
            holder2 = va_arg(arguments, double);
            if(holder1 > holder2)
                order = false;
        }
        else if(x % 2 != 0)
        {
            holder1 = va_arg(arguments, double);
            if(holder2 > holder1)
                order = false;
        }
    }
    va_end(arguments);
    return order;
}
```

The function attempts to determine if the numbers are inputted in ascending order but not matter what I pass the function returns false.

Comment: What is `holder2 = va_arg(arguments, double);`?

Comment: Maybe because everything inside the for-loop returns false so there's no possibility of anything else?

Comment: Did you try debugging this?

Comment: @CodingMash: They are defined in `<stdarg.h>` / `<cstdarg>`

Comment: @user1394965 the `false` statements only hit on the conditionals which would never be true if the arguments are in ascending order (as desired). The `order` var is set true before the loop and only remains that way if the loop completes without ever having an argument out of order.

Comment: Is is intentional that `num` is always ignored?

Comment: This is a *crazy* level of complexity for what you're trying to do. Consider [this pseduocode](http://pastie.org/5453763).

Comment: Not always: https://ideone.com/kTekqI

Comment: @meagar I think you should submit that as an answer. Unless there is an issue with the arguments themselves there is no reason why your code wouldn't accomplish the task.

Comment: @TheCapn It's horrible pseduocode that wouldn't compile in any language? It's not answer material.

Comment: @user1767077 : how are you calling this function ?

Comment: Hey could you accept an ans. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `if(x % 2 == 0)`  did you mean  to return `true` instead of `false`?

```
if(x % 2 == 0)
        {
            holder2 = va_arg(arguments, double);
            if(holder1 > holder2)
                order = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to this `va_start(arguments, args);` and remove the `num` from the declaration, you're processing an incorrect number of doubles and end up comparing with garbage  after the last arg.

Comment: 1. it's about counting `args` - maybe it's just 1-indexed; 2. it would help either; 3. presence of `num` is explicitly prohibit calling this function with one parameter -- maybe useful.

Comment: not sure why this was down-voted. It's an absolutely correct remark. The code in the question never checks `num`, but instead checks the `args` parameters after it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's easier to just start over with something simpler, and I think that's what I'd do in this case. First, I'd simplify the interface a bit:

```
bool ordered(int args, ...) { // ...
```

Then I'd simplify the code: retrieve a number. If it's smaller than the previous, return false. Otherwise, set previous to current, and read the next number. Continue for all the numbers. If you fall out of the loop (i.e., you reached the end without seeing a number that's out of order) return true.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues have been pointed out in the comments (the fact that `num` gets ignored eg. - see chill's answer for a solution to that), but if fixing those doesn't resolve your issue, then you're most likely not passing floating point values (either `float` or `double`) as parameters to the function.

If you are calling the function like this (assuming the `num` issue was fixed) :

```
bool result = ordered(3, 1, 2, 3);
```

then try calling it like this instead :

```
bool result = ordered(3, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
```